# How to resolve warning 'excess arguments to builtin `define' ignored' with m4

Tags: preprocessor, m4

I'm using m4 define to create a macro.
I tried using include(file) to read the content of the file as below.

```
 define(`TEST', include(file1))
 TEST
```

file1:

```
test -abc -LDFLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,/home/user -lmsg"
```

When I run the code, it gives a warning and doesn't print anything beyond -Wl

```
    m4:r1:1: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `define' ignored

    test -abc -LDFLAGS "-Wl
```

I tried using single quotes, but it didn't work.
Can someone please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If there are commas in the file, those will be interpreted as argument separators. The `include` replacement is inserted before determining the arguments to `define`.

Using single quotes is correct -- then the `include` will be processed in the output instead. For example:

```
define(`TEST', `include(file1)')
TEST
```

does work on my machine. (note that an even better solution is to add quotes around `file1` as well).